# Google Favicon Service: GitHub

Tags: api, github, favicon

I'm using the Google Favicon service and strangely it can't get the favicon from GitHub and just returns the default favicon.

- https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=github.com
- https://s2.googleusercontent.com/s2/favicons?domain=github.com

It works for other sites though.

- https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=stackoverflow.com

Does someone know what the cause could be? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps because it's being served from a different domain. This works:

```
https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=https://github.githubassets.com
```